# Union between two identical tables, each in a different database and connection (host, user, pass etc.)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds, dbeaver

Firstly, I'm using DBeaver as client to run SQL queries and access the data, from an AWS RDS Postgres database instance.

I have 2 connections named "Production" and "Production Backed".

These are the structures of each connections in DBeaver :

```
Production (Connection)
|_
  production (db)
  |_
    public (schema)
    |_
      table

Production Backed (Connection)
|_
  production (db)
  |_
    public (schema)
    |_
      table
```

I need to get a UNION table, by merging the 2 tables named "table", under each connection

DBeaver doesn't seem to provide such an option. Any ideas, or possibly other clients that might have that option will be highly valued and appreciated.

Comment: Are those two connections separate database servers?

Comment: Yes, they are in separate RDS instances

Comment: Then you will need to create a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html) in one of the database to access the table in the other.